# Can't disable link to WooCommerce single product page with BeTheme

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been trying to disable the single product page for specific categories in my website with no luck.

I've tried a lot of codes provided in previous topics with no results. I think this is due because I'm not using the default theme but Betheme.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close', 5 );
```

Alternatively I used pointer-events: none which worked on desktop but not on mobile (touch-action: none didn't do the trick either)

Link to the shop:

https://granitosdebrasil.com.ar/categoria/granito/

Comment: As BeThemes is a closed premium commercial theme, you should search in authors support threads and ask if you don't find what hook you need to use for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the link to the product page via this **CSS rule** *(it will work for both desktop and mobile)*:

```
li.isotope-item {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: none;
}
```

If you want to use PHP instead, as suggested by @LoicTheAztec, you should ask your theme support.